# Dropbox Image URLs

Tags: dropbox

Dropbox has 3 ways of showing the URL of an image.

**Type 1:** - This is the static image URL with jpg location:

[raw=1](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/esf7jqkntpl9snt/AADNow2ISkVXBxBHr3O8ze8Pa/GA-SBSC-W.jpg?raw=1)

**Type 2:** - This is the same image but when `raw=1` is replaced with `DL=0`, then the image is viewed on the Dropbox image viewer:

[DL=0](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/esf7jqkntpl9snt/AADNow2ISkVXBxBHr3O8ze8Pa/GA-SBSC-W.jpg?DL=0)

**Type 3:** This shows a grouped bundle of images and can have either `DL=0` or `raw=1` in the URL to either be viewed on the Dropbox viewer, or downloaded as a zip respectively:

[DL=0](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dimqln2qora21bj/AAC-LjhjwwpV0d1IVh7E--gda/CO-SIT?DL=0) or [raw=1](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dimqln2qora21bj/AAC-LjhjwwpV0d1IVh7E--gda/CO-SIT?raw=1)

Is there a way of amending the URL in the latter Type 3, to derive the physical static image URLS within the bundle?

Comment: If in the end, you just want the images, is the zip file not sufficient?

Comment: Might be possible via API https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation

Comment: No, the URLs are being used in a java program reading from a CSV. They will then be written as URLs to an exported CSV for upload to a POS system.

Comment: The API way might be an option. Thanks

Comment: If all else fails, you could download the zip, extract images, _upload_ them somewhere and use those links. :)

Answer (score 0):

The dropbox image URL can be amended from `dl=0` to `raw=1` to obtain the static absolute URL with .jpg or .png. However there is no current method of obtaining the child images within a folder.